# How to get child documents from parent collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongoDb.

I have 2 collections,

1st collection "ads"

```
ads = [
{
    _id: 1,
    companyId: 3,
    primaryText:"The world’s leading CRM is ready to help you simplify the business",
    headline: "Salesforce for Small Business",
  {
    _id: 2,
    companyId: 1,
    primaryText: "We like where you’re going with this.",
    headline: "Relaxed Fit Men's Jeans",
]
```

2nd collection

```
companies = [
  { _id: 1, name: "Levi's", url: "http://levis.com/" },
  { _id: 2, name: "Puma", url: "http://puma.com/" },
  { _id: 3, name: "Salesforce", url: "http://salesforce.com/" },
  { _id: 4, name: "Adidas", url: "http://adidas.com/" },
]
```

Let's say for a query I have found both the ads, now I want to get all those companies for which I have companyID in already found data.

```
const adsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: Number,
    companyId: String,
    primaryText: String,
    headline: String,
  }
);

const AdsModel = mongoose.model("ad", adsSchema);

let prods = await AdsModel.find({
        primaryText: { $regex: keyword, $options: "i" },
});
```

I am expecting to get the ads, which I am getting, but how can I also get all those companies with matching companyId

Comment: Try `$lookup` to join collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` in an `agreggation` instead of `find` like this: [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C1efyPKzInd)